# Redirect to https / HSTS script only works occasionally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

Well, I think the title says it all …

In my .htaccess file I've copied this code (from the internet):

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400"
```

I'm not sure if it does what I think it does. It should simply redirect to https … so if I load exampledomain.com it should become https://exampledomain.com and NOT http://exampledomain.com

The problem is: it works … sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work … so I ask my self: does this make sense?

Would be nice if anyone could explain this functionality to me … or tell me if I did something completely wrong?

THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSTS headers over HTTP are ignored.

You first need to redirect your visitors to HTTPS, and once your site is accessed using HTTPS it should return the Strict-Transport-Security header. The browser will then record this information, so future attempts to load the site using HTTP will automatically use HTTPS instead.

You can use this rewrite rule in your .htaccess to redirect from `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So, you mean, I should first redirect with mod_rewrite? Like this(?): RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: I have added the redirect rules for .htaccess, but if you can edit .conf files you should use them instead of .htaccess.

Comment: thx for your answers. no I have no access in this case. Is my redirect-script OK? I mean is it safe?

Comment: Your rewrite rule is OK (perhaps bit overcomplicated, so I suggested an alternative one)